# Index was outside the bounds of the array in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

im getting this error printing out the if statement

> Index was outside the bounds of the array

Codes:

```
Private Sub radsingle_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles radsingle.CheckedChanged

        With comDB
            .CommandText = SQL
            rdDB = .ExecuteReader
        End With
        While rdDB.Read

            If rdDB(1).ToString = txtptp.SelectedItem.ToString Then
                txtcdays.Text = rdDB(2).ToString.Trim

                'Radmulti.Checked = False
            End If
        End While

        rdDB.Close()

    End Sub
```

is there anything i've to change in this code..?

Comment: Datareader index starts from 0. Are you sure 2 is a valid column. Why not use `rdDB.Item("columnName")` ?

Comment: Providing the actual SQL would help, as would telling us which line the error occurs on. I'm going to guess that `rdDB(2)` is the issue and assume you only have 2 columns in your select. The index on the `DataReader` is 0 based.

Comment: I would also check for the existence of rows before calling `Read` as @abhitalks suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to use DataReader would be something on these lines:

```
If DataReader.HasRows Then
    While DataReader.Read()
    If rdDB.Item("ColumnName1").ToString = txtptp.SelectedItem.ToString Then
        ...
    End If
    End While
End If
```

This way you can check if DataReader contains rows or not, and also avoid confusions on index.

Of course, from your posted code it is unclear what the `SQL` variable holds. Possibly, your query is not returning any rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **Column Name** instead of Column Index